# Solutions to minimal surface equation by integration

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, curvature

Recently I'm studying homogenization for PDE, and trying to generalize a result for Dirichlet problem to minimal surface equation. The key point for this paper is to use Green's integral representation, so I'm wondering if  there is some kind of integral representation for minimal surface equation. Or under what special assumptions does this kind of representation exists?
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: This is a good question.  One possible answer to your question (though I'm not sure if it's quite what you're looking for) is the [Weierstrass parametrization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%E2%80%93Enneper_parameterization).

Comment: @JesseMadnick That's quite helpful, thank you.